# Need more information when exceptions are thrown using Log.setUncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I am using gwt-logs currently with GWT and GAE. I have my module
configured as explained in Getting Started:

```
<inherits name="com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.gwt-log-OFF" />
<inherits name="com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.gwt-log-RemoteLogger" />
<extend-property name="log_level" values="DEBUG" />
```

And I have my entry point class with:

```
Log.setUncaughtExceptionHandler()
```

The problem is when I get Uncaught Exception on the client side, all I
get in my GAE logs is:
"com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.server.ServerLogImplJDK14 log: Uncaught
Exception:"
I want to include more information on the source of the exception (ex:
class name, parameter, error type, exception stack trace). How do I
configure to do this?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code I see

```
  public final void setUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
      public void onUncaughtException(Throwable e) {
        Log.fatal("Uncaught Exception:", e);
      }
    });
    setErrorHandler();
  }
```

So it looks like you would either need to extend the class or set the uncaught exception handler again.

Comment: This isn't marked as an answer, but definitely worked for me.  Thanks Terra!